# Which bowler has played the most consecutive Test Matches?

Tags: cricket, trivia

In Test cricket, Allan Border played 153 consecutive Tests, the most of any player to date (September 2015). Which bowler has played most consecutive Test Matches?

Comment: Please define "bowler" in a quantitative manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, from the list of most consecutive test match appearances ([link](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283652.html)), filtering out the specialist batsmen and all-rounders, we get:

**Anil Kumble**, who played in India's **60** consecutive tests between 18 Oct 1992 and 2 Mar 2000. He is at 33rd position on the list.

If we include all rounders under bowlers, the "winner" is:

**Sir Gary Sobers**, who played in West Indies'  **85** consecutive tests between 11 Apr 1955 and   20 Apr 1972.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you define a bowler - Border has [39 test wickets](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/4174.html), so he could qualify!

Based on the [Cricinfo appearances list](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283652.html), the first player not primarily identified as a batsman (that I can see) is Garfield Sobers, who was an all-rounder. The first primary bowler I can see is Anil Kumble (not Glenn McGrath as previously stated).

Note that this is from a quick scan of the list, and opinions may vary.

Comment: Can you please let me know how many games did Mcgrath played consecutively.

Comment: If you click the link, find his name and click through to his profile, it'll tell you everything you need to know right there....